# How to collect a list of specific substrings following on a different substring trigger?

Tags: c#

I have a large text dataset (~2 GB) of engineering information that was written in Cobol.  I am attempting to extract certain substrings within it and make a CSV list with the extracted data.

The substrings of interest occur at known locations within each record.  However, there are no unique identifiers (primary keys) within the data itself.  It is simply a list of data where each "record" begins with a line starting in "01".  Every subsequent line belongs to that same record, until the next "01".  The presence of a given line might vary, but if present, data occurs at specific intervals.

The data looks like this:

```
Line1: 01253820RELEVANTSUBSTRING39ALSORELEVANT0990
Line2: 02999IRRELEVANT
Line3: 0420180101RELEVANTMONTHLYDATA000MORERELEVANTDATA8980
Line4: 0420190101FURTHERRELEVANTMONTHLYDATA
Line5: 12000003848982IRRELEVANT
Line6: 0100NEWRECORD8932000
Line7: 0420100101MORE
```

I have been able to successfully extract relevant substrings occurring after each "01" using the following code (partially included below):

```cs
static void PopulateList(){
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
    {
      string ctrl  //control key - indicates a new record if "01"

       List<TurbineModel> turbines = new List<TurbineModel>();

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath).ToList();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "01")
            {
                ctrl = line.Substring(0, 2);
                TurbineModel newWell = new TurbineModel();
                newTurbine.Ctrl = ctrl;

                turbines.Add(newTurbine);
            }
        }
      }
```

This code is working fine.  However, there are lines further down that begin with "04" which have other information that I have not been able to extract and group with the current "01" list.  I can extract substrings from every line that begins with an "04", but I don't have any way to link each record's data to the "01" record that preceded it.

What I need the code to do is the following:

1) Arrive at an "01" in the data and set up a new record
2) Extract relevant info from "01" line (per code above)
3) Skip subsequent lines unless it reaches an "04"
4) If it reaches an "04", extract substrings from that line and group those extracted substrings with the "01" substrings
5) Continue scanning lines until it reaches a new "01", at which point it sets up a new record and starts again
6) Output everything to CSV

I have been unable to group the information together so that I know which "04" relates to which "01".

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.  Let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: something you need is a good algorithm .to iterate through text .

Comment: You may want to consider streaming over `ReadAllLines()` if the file is 2GB.
Aside from that, you could write yourself a little parser that can "read" from the Cobol file in "chunks"...starts at the beginning and parses the file line by line. so, "01" == Start chunk{ while (stream.ReadLine() != '01'...Read each line into a dictionary, possibly, and yield your "chunk" as an object...you will be able to relate the "04" to the "01" as they belong to the same "chunk")

Comment: Or...take a look at https://www.filehelpers.net/ and see if that could help you parse.

Comment: Your example itself has two `04`s after the `01`. In that case do you need to extract information from both those lines or only the first of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that all you have to do is create a class that can store the data from the `01` line, and which can hold the relevant parts of the following lines.

Here's an example, where we loop through each line in the file, and if the line starts with `"01`, we create a new `Item` and add the line as it's `Data` (you could do some processing of the line contents instead to populate other properties). If the line doesn't start with `"01"` and we've already created an `Item`, then we add the line to the item's `AssociatedLines` property if it starts with `"04"` (you could also process the line in some way and add the relevant parts to the `Item` instead).

At the end, we have a list of `Item` objects that were each created from a line that begins with `"01`" and which contain all the lines after that until the next line that starts with `"01"`.

First, the `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<string> AssociatedData { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    // This returns a comma-separated line representing this item
    public string GetCsvString()
    {
        return $"{Data},{string.Join(",", AssociatedData)}";
    }
}
```

And then the code that creates a list of these based on the file data:

```
public static List<Item> GetItems(string filePath)
{
    var items = new List<Item>();
    Item current = null;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("01"))
        {
            // If there's already a current item, add it to our list
            if (current != null) items.Add(current);

            // Here we would parse the '01' line and set properties of the current item
            current = new Item {Data = line};
        }
        else if (line.StartsWith("04"))
        {
            // Here we would parse the '04' line and set properties of the current item
            current?.AssociatedData.Add(line);
        }
    }

    // Add the final item to our list
    if (current != null) items.Add(current);

    return items;
}
```

And then the code that calls the method above would simply look like:

```
var items = GetItems(@"f:\public\temp\temp.txt");
```

Extracting an item to a `CSV` file would probably best be done by either overriding the `ToString()` method on the `Item` class or providing a `GetCsvString()` method that spits out the relevant data in the correct format. After which, you could write the items to a csv file like:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"f:\public\temp\temp.csv", items.Select(item => item.GetCsvString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go, it's a "chunk reader" :) I have used something similar in the past. It may need some work, but it parses your sample into 2 "chunks".

```
namespace Solution
{
    class Solution
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var reader = new ChunkReader();
            Chunk chunk = null;

            foreach (Chunk c in reader.Read(@"D:\test.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Header);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    internal class ChunkReader
    {
        public IEnumerable<Chunk> Read(string filePath)
        {
            Chunk currentChunk = null;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
            {
                string currentLine;

                while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (currentLine.StartsWith("01"))
                    {
                        if (currentChunk != null)
                        {
                            yield return currentChunk;
                        }

                        currentChunk = new Chunk();
                        currentChunk.Contents.Add(currentLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentChunk?.Contents.Add(currentLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            yield return currentChunk;
        }
    }

    internal class Chunk
    {
        public Chunk()
        {
            Contents = new SortedSet<string>();
        }

        public SortedSet<string> Contents { get; }

        public string Header
        {
            get
            {
                return Contents.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("01"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as some others have suggested, if your file is really large you should consider an alternative to `File.ReadAllLines()` as it can get costly. But since the question is not about that, I'm moving past that.

First, two dummy functions to mimic extracting your necessary data once you know if a line begins with either `01` or `04`.

```
static string Extract01Data(string line)
{
    return line;
}

static string Extract04Data(string line)
{
    return line;
}
```

### EDIT

Edited the answer to accommodate multiple lines that begin with `04` that come after the first `01` line:

And a simple class to hold your resulting data:

```
public class Record
{
    public string OneInfo { get; set; }
    public List<string> FourInfo { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then, here's my code, with explanations in comments:

```
static void Main()
{
    var file = @"C:\Users\gurudeniyas\Desktop\CobolData.txt";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();

    var records = new List<Record>();

    for (var count = 0; count < lines.Count; count++)
    {
        var line = lines[count];
        var firstTwo = line.Substring(0, 2);
        // Iterate till we find a line that starts with 01
        if (firstTwo == "01")
        {
            // Create a Record and add 01 line related data
            var rec = new Record
            {
                OneInfo = Extract01Data(line)
            };

            // Here we iterate to find preceding lines that start with 03
            // If we find them, extract 04 data and add as a record
            // Break out of the loop if we find the next 01 line or EOF
            do
            {
                count++;
                if (count == lines.Count)
                    break;
                line = lines[count];
                firstTwo = line.Substring(0, 2);
                if (firstTwo == "04")
                {
                    rec.FourInfo.Add(Extract04Data(line));
                }
            } while (firstTwo != "01");

            // If we found next 01, backtrack count by 1 so in the outer loop we can process that record again
            if (firstTwo == "01")
            {
                count--;
            }
            records.Add(rec);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, it looks like there can be multiple "04" records after a "01" record.

Answer (score 1):

If the "04" always follows the 01 you can just add an else if as below, and then access the last item in your list (this will work because adding a item to a list adds it to the end).

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "01")
    {
        ctrl = line.Substring(0, 2);
        TurbineModel newWell = new TurbineModel();
        newTurbine.Ctrl = ctrl;

        turbines.Add(newTurbine);
     }
     else if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "04")
     {
        var lastTurbine = turbines[turbines.Count - 1];
        //do what you need to do with the "04" record monthly data here
     }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing site, I gave enough info for him to derive a solution.

Comment: like i said i don't write complete code, that is up to the OP. I gave him an idea of how he could fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at using a finite state machine algorithm? Seems ideal for this.

Comment: you can post your answer as a comment

Comment: Well, with 8 rep you can't, but this is still not an answer.